# R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component? How to render this model

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to render in a 3D model to my website, and I'm receiving the error "R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!" I'm using react and three.js.

Here is my code for the Home.js file (The home page), as you can see I try to implement `<Model1 />` and it is within a canvas

```
<Canvas
              className={`w-full h-screen bg-transparent ${isRotating ? 'cursor-grabbing' : 'cursor-grab'}`}
              camera={{ near: 0.1, far: 1000, position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 10 }}
            >
              <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
              <pointLight position={[10, 5, 10]} intensity={2} />
              <directionalLight position={[1, 1, 1]} intensity={2} /> 
              <spotLight position={[10, 5, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} intensity={2} />
              <Suspense fallback={loader}>
                <Model1 
                  position={modelPosition}
                  rotation={[0.1, 4.7077, 0]}
                  scale={modelScale}
                  isRotating={isRotating}
                  setIsRotating={setIsRotating}
                />
              </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
```

I also have this function in my home.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    adjustModelForScreenSize();
    const handleResize = () => adjustModelForScreenSize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  const loader = <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...</div>;
```

And my model1.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";

const Model1 = ({ position, rotation, scale, isRotating, setIsRotating, ...props }) => {
const modelRef = useRef();
const { scene } = useGLTF("/character_mannequin_male.glb");

useFrame(() => {
if (isRotating && modelRef.current) {
modelRef.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }
  });

return (
    <primitive
object={scene}
ref={modelRef}
position={position}
rotation={rotation}
scale={scale}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

useGLTF.preload("/character_mannequin_male.glb");

export default Model1;
```

I'm new to using 3d models. There is also lots of more code that I'm not including because I'm not sure if it would be useful.

I tried to implement a 3d model into my website, I expected the 3d model to be implemented and for me to be able to use my cursor to drag it and rotate it, the result was the error and the whole website not loading.

Comment: Can you implement the window resize handler inside of Model1 instead of inside Home.js?

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and it worked for a second and then i got this error: R3F: Span is not part of the THREE namespace!

Comment: Unless the model resize function introduces a span element, I'm not seeing where it comes from. Canvas expects to be contained within a dom element, but not contain dom elements within itself. I DO see the Suspense element though... I would try wrapping the Suspense element around the entire canvas. If necessary, use CSS positioning to place it "inside" the canvas.

I am also new to three.js. I just recently learned it is attempting to stay at the forefront by using the new webGPU in place of webGL so I figure it's worth looking into.  I do have tons of experience (10+ years) generally.